# Secure communication between Android and PHP

Tags: php

My client wants me to develop a php application which will communicate with Android devices. I want to only allow requests from my clients application. I thought of key exchange but its insecure. I am not concerned about data encryption I only want my client's application communicate with my php application.

Comment: This cannot be done. There is no way to attach a credential to code. You can make it slightly annoying to crack, and that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple steam cipher may be the only way to help you, depending on how secure you want to be. You could also look into checking the User Agent, if you make it something difficult to guess then you are at least OK until someone decompiles the android application or checks the packet info. The problem is that due to Android applications being capable of being decompiled, you can never be that secure.